# My R plot font size is incorrect?

Tags: r, font-size

I am trying to output r plots as .eps files and use them in illustrator. However I don`t seem to get the correct fontsize in the output. An easy example:

```
library(ggplot2)
data<-data.frame(RLU=c(0.24,384.04), type=c("9 Balalexpression", "Induktion"))
setEPS()
postscript(width=6.5/2.54, height = 4/2.54, file = "pTRELUCReporter.eps")
p<-ggplot(data, aes(x=type, y=RLU))
p+geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="grey")+
  xlab("")+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=9),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=9),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=9)
        )
dev.off()
```

This results in an output eps file. I now next import the the file into Illustrator and the fontsize seems to be too big:

[image: The Arial and Helvetica Text was added as a size reference]

Allready the output eps file seems to have fonts bigger than 9 pt so I am tempted to exclude import issues. The R reference for element_text says the size is in pts..  can anywone explain what I am getting wrong here? I would love to understand this thing as I will have to generate many figures with exactly set fontsizes :(

Thanks a lot!

Comment: And if you use option `pointsize = 9` in `postscript` function call? Also why you divide by 2.54 width and height options - these are already in inches.

Comment: I added pointsize=9  in the postscript call. This had no effect however. I divide by 2.54, because I prefer the metric system. Yes - I am european! I hope someone will help me anyway :)

Comment: I've reproduced your example and tried to compare fontsizes in Inkscape. Letters on axis are exactly of the same size and shape as when I create text object with Arial 9.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the behaviour and output of your code. Ghostscript is the same.
With the `width=6.5/2.54` option in your `postscript()` function you are setting the width of the graphics region only. This doesn't necessarily mean you are downscaling all included elements in your eps file.

If you downsize your text in the graphics by 2.54 the result looks what you might need.

```
library(ggplot2)
data<-data.frame(RLU=c(0.24,384.04), type=c("9 Balalexpression", "Induktion"))
setEPS()
postscript(width=6.5/2.54, height = 4/2.54, file = "pTRELUCReporter.eps")
p<-ggplot(data, aes(x=type, y=RLU))
p+geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="grey")+
    xlab("")+
    theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=9/2.54),
          axis.text.x=element_text(size=9/2.54),
          axis.text.y=element_text(size=9/2.54)
    )
dev.off()
```

Comment: I just tried this scaling but it results in text that is much smaller than 9 pt.

Comment: The easy way seems to just play around with the value until I find something which looks right. This is not very satisfactory though. Why is 9pt in my r example different from 9pt in word, illustrator,...?  I also tried not giving any width or height options in the postscript call, but now I got a Figure much larger than before with text labels allready smaller than 9 pt...

Comment: Trying to reproduce inscaven's comment above (with inkscape) but did not succeed. Even more: when comapring my proposal above confusing is my o

Comment: when comparing my proposal above to without the code without dividing by 2.54 (in 'postscript()' and 'element_text()', the resulting eps files look different. Their graphic regions are filled differently... It really looks confusing and unsatisfactory as you said..